# Drop-down Menus in Standard Drupal 7.4 Zen theme?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm new to Drupal so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.
I'm trying to implement a drop-down menu in Drupal 7.4 in the Zen theme with only a standard install (I'm trying to avoid installing other modules). 
There appears to be no easy way to do this. 
Is the only option to manually code one of the CSS files in the subtheme directory for this effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wNt to install other modules then your only option is to create the CSS / JavaScript needed for it in your theme.

If you don't want to use a module, take a look at [nice_menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus).

Comment: Thanks for the response! And supposing I were to look into modules... everything apart from Superfish doesn't seem to have a stable version for 7.x. Thoughts on this?